# Segment violation when modifying a string

Tags: c, pthreads

I have a small problem with a program that when running, sends me a segmentation violation apparently occurs in the function "ejer6" when trying to access the `position [0]` of `char * mensaje` to assign `9` my code :

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

struct structure {

    char * message;
    int integer;
};

void * ejer6(void * arg) {

    printf("Enters within");

    struct structure * turas;
    turas=((struct structure *)arg;

    turas->integer=turas->integer+1;
    turas->message[0]='9';

    printf("%d\n", turas->integer);
    printf("%s\n", turas->message);


    pthread_exit(NULL);
}

int main(int argc, char ** argv) {
    if(argc!=2) {
        printf("Enter the appropriate number of parameters\n");
    }
    else {

        pthread_t h[argc];
        struct structure turas[argc];
        int i;

        for(i=0; i<argc; i++) {
            turas[i].integer=13;
            turas[i].message="hello world";
        }

        for(i=0; i<argc; i++) {

            printf("\nThis is the value of the structure before the strand: \n");
            printf("Integer: %d \n", turas[i].integer);
            printf("Message: %s \n", turas[i].message);


            pthread_create(&h[i], NULL, ejer6, (void *)&turas[i]);
            pthread_join(h[i], NULL);

            printf("\nThis is the value of the structure after the strand: \n");
            printf("Integer: %d \n", turas[i].integer);
            printf("Message: %s \n", turas[i].message);

        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: what's the point of creating threads if you execute them sequentially?

Comment: You may want to have a look [here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/266563/do-non-english-words-increase-the-probability-of-receiving-downvotes/) to understand how non-english code reduces your chance to get good answers.

Answer (score 1):

`turas->mensaje` points to a string literal, which you are attempting to modify. This is *undefined behaviour* in C. Use an array or allocate memory for `turas->mensaje` and copy the string literal into it.

You can use `strdup()` (posix function) to allocate memory:

```
turas[i].mensaje=strdup("Hola mundo");
```

instead of

```
 turas[i].mensaje="Hola mundo";
```

Now, you will be able to modify it and you'll have to `free` the memory allocated by `strdup()`.

Comment: and "malloc" would be something : turas[i].mensaje = malloc(argc * 12);

Comment: Not sure why include a factor `argc`. If you prefer to use `malloc()`, allocate enough memory for string and use strcpy()` to copy the string: `turas[i].mensaje=malloc(strlen("Hola mundo")+1); strcpy(turas[i].mensaje, "Hola mundo");` you should also check if `malloc()` fails.